# Procesar formulario con id a php

Tags: php, javascript

tengo un formulario que recibe su valor desde un archivo js, el archivo pasa esta variable al formulario

```
 $('#miticket').val(cuenta);
```

El contenido se muestra de forma exitosa en mi formulario, el problema es que cuando proceso el formulario el campo pasa vacio, no me muestra ningun dato. Estoy procesando con php, por lo que al menos al hacer click en el formulario deberia pasar el dato que estoy colocando en el campo.

el resultado en la siguiente pagina es $billete vacio

Formulario html

```
<form id="wallet" action="../resources/upticket.php" method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Tu billete </label>
                          <input type="text" name="billete" class="form-control" id="miticket" disabled>

                        </div>
                      </div>


                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning pull-right">Vincular</button>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </form>
```

Comment: En donde defines la variable `$billete`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso se debe a que tu input esta como **disabled**

Como menciona la página de [W3C schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp)

> Tip: Disabled  elements in a form will not be submitted!

Tendrías que quitar ese valor a tu input, y ya con eso, el valor debería ser enviado por el formulario.

```
<form id="wallet" action="../resources/upticket.php" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Tu billete </label>
                <input type="text" name="billete" class="form-control" id="miticket">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning pull-right">Vincular</button>
    </div>
</form>
```